# Apache poi 5.2.2 - XWPFRun setText() error

Tags: android, apache-poi, xwpf

I used Apache poi 4.1.2 and everything worked well .
I tried the same code with the new version of Apache poi (5.2.2)
and the error occurs when I use run.setText()

```kotlin
fun function(){
val document = XWPFDocument()
val paragraph = document!!.createParagraph()
        paragraph!!.alignment = alignment
        val run = paragraph!!.createRun()
        run!!.setText(text) --------> here the the error occurs
}
```

and i get this error:

```
E/org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.e.testpoi, PID: 20131
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.e.testpoi/com.e.testpoi.MainActivity}: 
org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: Cannot resolve type for handle _XY_Q=space|R=space@http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace (org.apache.poi.schemas.ooxml.system.ooxml.cttext7f5btype) - code 13
     Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: Cannot resolve type for handle _XY_Q=space|R=space@http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace (org.apache.poi.schemas.ooxml.system.ooxml.cttext7f5btype) - code 13
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.XsbReader.readHandle(XsbReader.java:483)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.XsbReader.readTypeRef(XsbReader.java:548)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.XsbReader.loadAttribute(XsbReader.java:1282)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.XsbReader.readAttributeData(XsbReader.java:1275)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.XsbReader.finishLoadingType(XsbReader.java:902)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeSystemImpl.resolveHandle(SchemaTypeSystemImpl.java:938)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaComponent$Ref.getComponent(SchemaComponent.java:113)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType$Ref.get(SchemaType.java:1072)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaPropertyImpl.getType(SchemaPropertyImpl.java:85)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeImpl.createElementType(SchemaTypeImpl.java:990)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.create_element_user(XmlObjectBase.java:914)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.getUser(Xobj.java:1597)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.getUser(Cur.java:2571)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.insertElement(Xobj.java:2012)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.add_element_user(Xobj.java:2093)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTRImpl.addNewT(CTRImpl.java:318)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun.setText(XWPFRun.java:362)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun.setText(XWPFRun.java:349)
```

this is the single dependency i use
build.gradle(app):

```
   implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")
```

tried with/without these and the error didn't solve

```
    implementation("org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:5.0.3")
```

Tried these, Didn't work as well

```
   implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-full:5.2.2")
   implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:5.2.2")
```

Comment: @AxelRichter Hi thanks for your comment, I tried  5.0.3 version for org.apache.xmlbeans with poi 5.2.2 , mentioned it in the post , it didn't solve the exception.(I edited the post and removed ```stax-api``` maybe it led  to confusion)

Comment: @AxelRichter 100% , Im only using ```implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")```

Comment: @AxelRichter maybe Im missing something ? I have only
```implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.2")``` in my build.gradle(app) . I don't have any .jars , because it leads to the same result. In addition , I don't use ```ooxml-lite``` ```ooxml-full``` because it doesn't help. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, cannot help. I had overseen the `android` tag. That `android` Java is not complete Java as default Java JREs are. So ...

Comment: @AxelRichter sorry for my lack of understanding, how do you use apache poi ? How can I make it work, if its not an android project?

Comment: Apache POI is a Java API made to run in default Java environments using a default JDK respective JRE, as used in Windows and or Linux OS for example. But `adroid` Java is not default Java. It lacks AWT for example but seems it lacks some XML features too which default Java has. But I am not an Android expert. That's why I cannot really help here.